# How to embolden an asterisk?

Tags: support, markdown, markdown-rendering

I've read the instructions for writing questions, answers and comments: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting and read the markdown documentation: http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#backslash but I can't get an asterisk to be in bold. I've tried html as well.

For reference, a non-bold asterisk:

```
*
```

gives *

```
**\***
```

gives *****

```
<b>*</b>
```

gives *****

```
******
```

gives ******

```
*****
```

gives *****

using the bold button on the GUI gives *****

I wanted this to emphasis an operator in a list or arithmetic operators.

Comment: Works for me in Chrome. The difference **is there**. Compare (bold and regular) side by side: **\*** *

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about behavior that doesn't exist. Your attempts to bold asterisks are already successful. Those asterisks **are** bold.

Comment: **\*** \* **\*** \* **\*** \* **\*** \* **\*** \* **\*** \* **\*** \* **\*** \* **\*** \* **\*** \* **\*** \* **\*** \* **\*** \* **\*** \* **\*** \* **\*** \* **\*** \* **\*** \* **\*** \* **\*** \* **\*** \* **\*** \* **\*** \* **\*** \* **\*** \* **\*** \* **\*** \* **\*** \* **\*** \* **\*** \* **\*** \*

Comment: I recommend offering it a beer. Or a kiss.

Answer (score 15):

For `**\***` and `<b>*</b>`, they are actually bolded.  It's just that asterisks don't look very different when bolded.  (Do an inspect element on them; it does generate tags for it but they aren't visually different)

If you do it in code formatting, it is somewhat visible (still not very, though).  Compare:

`non-bold *`
`yes-bold *`

Note that you need to use actual `<code></code>` tags here: I wrote the above as this:

```
<code>non-bold \*</code>  
<code>yes-bold <b>\*</b></code>
```

Answer (score 3):

## * - super bold :)

***** **-** **bold**.

* - not bold.

You seem to have shown it, but **it works**...

Comment: Your asterisk are not in bold for me. (Chrome on Windows 7 BTW)

Comment: Works for me in Chrome and Safari...

Comment: Bold and not bold look *awfully* similar on Chrome. Super bold works well

Comment: I think font choices can throw this off really easily. If I look at this answer with SO's stylesheet, I don't see a difference between the bold and not bold asterisk (the rest is clearly different). If I turn off SO's stylesheet, I see a *slight* difference between the asterisks. Probably playing with fonts some more, I'd find settings where there is a bigger difference.

Comment: @Louis I think this happens in pretty much any font. An asterisk is a very tiny character. If you bold it *too* much, it just becomes a dot.

Comment: The bold asterisk actually looks smaller on my screen (Chrome, Windows 7). Super bold looks better, but everything on the line needs to be bold for that markup to work.

Comment: Thanks everybody. That helped me see what was going on.

Comment: So ... what does the markdown code you used to produce this look like?

Comment: @HelloGood, That's the source of the post: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/b3f888ba-d51a-4675-b416-b397377920b7/view-source

Comment: Thanks for the link. Usually, you can see the source by pressing "edit," but that doesn't seem to work for this post.

Comment: @HelloGoodbye That's because it's Meta Stack Overflow. Unlike the main site, Stack Overflow, there's no such thing as suggesting edits to posts, and here you can edit posts only since you've got [2000 rep - that's the threshold to edit **immediately** both at Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Overflow, without suggesting and waiting for review](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit).

Comment: Worth to notice that here on Meta you can still edit Community Wiki posts and, of course, your own posts.

Comment: Ah, I get it. How can I see the source of other posts on Stackexchange pages?

Comment: @HelloGoodbye you go to the link such as /posts/{ID}/revisions, choose the revision you like and click the corresponding "source" link

Comment: @HelloGood, example of such link: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/281438/revisions

Answer (score 3):

Just found that the only way is to not use the "*" character, use `&ast;` instead e.g.

`**&ast;**` gives *****

Bold *****

Normal *

Screen shot

[image]

Comment: That looks exactly the same to me (Chrome Version 75.0.3770.100 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Windows 10)...

Comment: interesting, I am using the latest Chrome on Windows 10 64 bit and difference is clear. If you take screen shoot and load it up into a paint program and zoom in can you see the differences? The only thing I can think of is my screen resolution is only 1920x1080

Comment: [Here's a screenshot of what I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCKsh.png). If anything the bold one is smaller than the normal one... Maybe I'm at 100% instead of Windows' normal 125% text size?

Comment: I can see there is no difference in your screenshot so I posted my own, where I can see the difference, but it is not huge.

Comment: Ha! The bold one looks like a person flexing muscles! :)